# FFmpeg api generating distorted image when using 422 or 420 chroma subsampling and SD resoltuion

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I created an application based on FFmpeg api. The application reads video frames, does some processing, then writes the processed video frames to a new file. The application is working perfectly fine in most circumstances. However, I'm facing weird output when the application is configured to use 420 or 422 chroma subsampling with SD resolution (720x480). When using 420 or 422 chroma subsampling with HD resolution (1920x1080), the output turns out fine. With the distorted output I can see the problem is with the subsampled channels. The Y channel looks good, but Cr and Cb seem to be distorted.

I am not using any specific codec options in the encoder and can replicate the issue with either prores or hevc codecs. If I output to raw binary video files I can't see any issues which confirms that the problem is happening sometime during encoding and the binary data fed into the AVFrame is properly formatted after subsampling.

The images can be seen below:

[Original input video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDql5.jpg)

[Correct output video (HD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIrPe.png)

[Distorted output video (SD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgXbQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears FFmpeg requires you to honor some memory alignment constraints. FFmpeg might add some padding per line (refer to AVFrame linesize) depending on the pixel format, height, and width you're using. The way I fixed this is to extract the linesize after calling av_frame_alloc and setting format, height, and width. You want to calculate the actual data size you have per line (based on width and pixel size), then push your cursor to multiples of linesize so you can read the next lines. Another thing to note is this behavior is mostly noticed on planar formats, not packed ones.